# is it ok for a view model to listen for changes on its own properties?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

Let's say I have a view model with property A and a property B. Whenever A changes, I need to update B accordingly, who others might be listening too as well. Is it ok if my view model listens for changes to its own property A? or should the view model only expose these properties for the view controller to react accordingly and let the latter be the one who updates B? I also read somewhere that view controllers should be "if-free" as there shouldn't be any decisions on them. I kinda like that idea as it should lead to keep my view controllers really short but that doesn't go along well with the idea of making it to be responsible for updating property B. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on how A and B are altered. If A is only going to be changed from inside your view, then implement this change from within the view without exposing the unnecessary property. If the controller might change the property, and there are functions that will Alter A and B outside the view, then it is better to let the controller handle it and unify it to the view controller.

Hope this helps!